# .net cf TextBox that displays keyboard on focus

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a few text boxes on my UI that I want to display the mobile keyboard for when the control has focus, then go away.

Note: for this particular program, it is a tall screen and has no physical keyboard on the device.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add an InputPanel to your Form, hook up the GotFocus and LostFocus events of the TextBox and show/hide the input panel in the event handlers:

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetKeyboardVisible(true);
}

private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetKeyboardVisible(false);
}

protected void SetKeyboardVisible(bool isVisible)
{
    inputPanel.Enabled = isVisible;
}
```

**Update**

In response to ctacke's request for completeness; here is sample code for hooking up the event handlers. Normally I would use the designer for this (select the textbox, show the property grid, switch to the event list and have the environment set up handlers for `GotFocus` and `LostFocus`), but if the UI contains more than a few text boxes you may wish to have it more automated.

The following class exposes two static methods, AttachGotLostFocusEvents and DetachGotLostFocusEvents; they accept a ControlCollection and two event handlers.

```
internal static class ControlHelper
{
    private static bool IsGotLostFocusControl(Control ctl)
    {
        return ctl.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(TextBoxBase)) ||
           (ctl.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox) && (ctl as ComboBox).DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDown);
    }

    public static void AttachGotLostFocusEvents(
        System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection controls,
        EventHandler gotFocusEventHandler,
        EventHandler lostFocusEventHandler)
    {
        foreach (Control ctl in controls)
        {
            if (IsGotLostFocusControl(ctl))
            {
                ctl.GotFocus += gotFocusEventHandler;
                ctl.LostFocus += lostFocusEventHandler ;
            }
            else if (ctl.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                AttachGotLostFocusEvents(ctl.Controls, gotFocusEventHandler, lostFocusEventHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DetachGotLostFocusEvents(
        System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection controls,
        EventHandler gotFocusEventHandler,
        EventHandler lostFocusEventHandler)
    {
        foreach (Control ctl in controls)
        {
            if (IsGotLostFocusControl(ctl))
            {
                ctl.GotFocus -= gotFocusEventHandler;
                ctl.LostFocus -= lostFocusEventHandler;
            }
            else if (ctl.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                DetachGotLostFocusEvents(ctl.Controls, gotFocusEventHandler, lostFocusEventHandler);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example in a form:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ControlHelper.AttachGotLostFocusEvents(
        this.Controls,
        new EventHandler(EditControl_GotFocus),
        new EventHandler(EditControl_LostFocus));
}

private void Form_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ControlHelper.DetachGotLostFocusEvents(
        this.Controls,
        new EventHandler(EditControl_GotFocus),
        new EventHandler(EditControl_LostFocus));
}

private void EditControl_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowKeyboard();
}

private void EditControl_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideKeyboard();
}
```

Comment: I was just reading this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838220.aspx , they also recommend catching the Form_Closing event.

Comment: For completeness you should probably show wiring up the events too.

Comment: @FredrikMörk Great Code and in detail explained. Thanx a lot, everything works for me, but I need one more small thing the inputPanel is small keyboard how can change this to large keyboard

Answer (score 5):

Use the [InputPanel class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.inputpanel.aspx).  [Enable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.inputpanel.enabled.aspx) it when you get focus, disable it when you lose focus.