# Bringing up numeric keyboard automatically on editing textbox (.NET CF)

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, compact-framework, textbox

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967281/net-cf-textbox-that-displays-keyboard-on-focus) explains in detail how to bring up/hide the virtual keyboard on getting/losing focus on a control. However in my TextBox, I want the user to type numbers, so it were nice if I could switch the virtual keyboard to numeric input directly. Do you have any proposals how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/52f39185-5fc4-45aa-8eb4-3d2681eb891e). I think that's what you're looking for...