# Automatically display keyboard in Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Using C#, is there a way to automatically display the keyboard when a text box is activated in Windows Mobile 5 and 6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net cf TextBox that displays keyboard on focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967281/net-cf-textbox-that-displays-keyboard-on-focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call when text box is activated (got focus)

```
  InputPanel.Enabled = True
```

please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967281/net-cf-textbox-that-displays-keyboard-on-focus).

Comment: thanks. more accurately the code looks like:
new Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.InputPanel().Enabled = true;

Comment: No, that is not more accurate.  You shouldn't be creating a new InpoutPanel every time you get activated.  You should put an InputPanel in the Form's components or at the class level and use that one.

Comment: ctacke, Thanks for pointing this out because it caused me to figure out that you need to dispose InputPanel objects. Is there any other reason why you should not create one every time you want to enable or disable the SIP? Anyway, the purpose of my comment was to point out that the code posted by Ram does not compile since the Enabled property is not static. However I still marked his post as the answer since he turned me onto the InputPanel class and the Enabled property and linked to the answer.